# Get bitmap of videoview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-videoview

Is there a way to take a screenshot of a video playing in video view. I searched on the forum but could not get the required info. I tried with

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.view.getWidth(), this.view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.draw(canvas);
```

and

```
mCustomVideoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap videoView = mCustomVideoView.getDrawingCache(false);
```

But none of these methods were helpful.

Comment: Not sure, but you can simply ask Android for a thumbnail with ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(); if you can point it to the video with a path...

Comment: But my requirement is different. It is a sort of health monitor systems of an app where I need to take screenshot of what is playing. Whereas thumbnail will always give me same image

Comment: Then maybe this can help you? Seems to be a working way to take a screenshot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: @Ankuj Are you asking to get the thumbnail for the video view.

Comment: yes janmejoy, I am trying to get a thumbnail of video view

Comment: @Ankuj- Did you able to get this solved! I also stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it with that:

```
videoview.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bitmap = yourvideoview.getDrawingCache(); 
 java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();  

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 90, stream); 

byte[] videoByteArray=stream.toByteArray(); String video_str = Base64.encodeToString(videoByteArray, 0);
```

The output is the String video_str and the Bitmap bitmap.